# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'method'

Tags: python, pyspark

I am converting hive sql using spark dataframe api operations. One of the use case requires to verify a string column for blank and NULL.

I wrote below code to satisfy the requirement

```
when(trim(get_sor_tab_df["X"]) == 'D',
  when((trim(get_sor_tab_df["X1"]) != '' & get_sor_tab_df["X1"].isNotNull), trim(get_sor_tab_df["X2"])))
    .when(df2_lkp["r_code8"].isNotNull,df2_lkp["r_code8"]).otherwise(coalesce(trim(get_sor_tab_df["X3"]), lit("")))

(trim(get_sor_tab_df["X1"]) != '' & get_sor_tab_df["X1"].isNotNull)
```

this check is giving me error. How can i satisfy this condition?

Comment: Please, format the code properly, so that we can actually read it.

Comment: And also, explain what you have tried to fix the error.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] including sample input and output, and the full error traceback for your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isNotNull` is a function; you forgot the `()`.

You also need parenthesis around each condition, because the `&` has higher operator precedence than `==`/`!=`.

I believe this is logically equivalent to what you have, with intentionally weird formatting to make sure the parens are balanced and that the logical grouping is there:

```
when( ( (trim(get_sor_tab_df["X"]) == 'D')
      & ( (trim(get_sor_tab_df["X1"]) != '') 
        & (get_sor_tab_df["X1"].isNotNull())
        )
      ),
      trim(get_sor_tab_df["X2"]) 
    )
.when(df2_lkp["r_code8"].isNotNull(), df2_lkp["r_code8"])
.otherwise(coalesce(trim(get_sor_tab_df["X3"]), lit("")))
```

I would recommend pulling out the complex column expressions into variables to clean this up.